# Set Tag value in xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin, Is there any way to set tag to button in xaml file?

I tried this,

```
<Button Text="OK"
 Tag="{Binding Email}"/>
```

but Tag property doesn't supporting in xaml

what property is there in xaml to support to set tag value to view

Comment: You want some value on button click, right?

Comment: No, i want to set value to view as tag so that later i can retrieve from class

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create your own custom `Button` and add a Tag `BindableProperty`.

```
public class ButtonWithTag : Button
{
    public object Tag
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(TagProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TagProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Tag), typeof(object), typeof(ButtonWithTag), null);
}
```

You use it like this in XAML

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectName"

    <local:ButtonWithTag 
        Text="Ok"
        Tag="{Binding Email}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution for this is CommandParameter. You can do this using CommandParameter. Try this,

.xaml

```
<Button Text="OK"
        Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
        CommandParameter="EmailAddress"/>
```

.cs

```
ICommand tapCommand;

public ICommand TapCommand {
    get { return tapCommand; }
}

public ConstructorName {
tapCommand = new Command (OnTapped);
}

void OnTapped (object s)  {
    Debug.WriteLine ("parameter: " + s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x:Name="MyButton"`, and then access the button in your code-behind .cs file by simply using `MyButton.Text = "updated text"`, for example. Assuming thats what you meant.

Comment: I don't want to set text i want to set tag , it should not display on view.it should be stored in that view so that later i can retrieve same

Comment: Right, I was just using it as an example. In that case, I suppose you can use `MyButton.Tag = ...`

Comment: Tag property doesn't support in xaml. what property is there in xaml to set tag

Comment: Xamarin Forms doesn't have a Tag property for views. You can create a custom button renderer though, and add your own Tag property

Comment: Any idea how to do custom render for tag property